# Simple (app) way to send payment request to an address

Tags: payments, mainnet

I am sorry for the lame question, but I am a bit lost here.

Background: My wife got scammed off of 2 ETH. We can see the transaction at: [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) and the address the ETH went to.

I know that:

- transactions are irreversible
- there is very little chance on retrieving the funds

But nonetheless I came up with few stupid ideas, I feel I need to do (to exhaust all options).

My bet is not many of the scammed people have technical skills (obviously I lack some too). So they have never sent any request to get the money back. My bet continues that if this scam is an elaborate ring - where many people and addresses are involved, I might have a tiny, little chance when my payment request is received the guy to transfer the ETH back to me, thinking he's sending it to another gang member.

I've tried several apps and [request.network](https://request.network/) but so far I haven't found an easy way to send a request directly to another address on the mainnnet. I have some technical skill and I have access to a shared hosting account, I hope I will be able to manage with some guidance. I will report how it went :)